# Sublime Text 3-Material Theme

Tags: text

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH04s.jpg)

How can I change "Explorer" and that green background with normal tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove it by removing the [marterial-theme-appbar](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme-appbar) package in Sublime Text.

`cmd+shift+p` to bring up the command pallet, then choose 'Package Control: Remove Package' then search for *appbar* and remove the Material Theme Appbar.

After I uninstalled the package I had to activate the Material theme again (Preferences > Package Settings > Material Theme > Activate).